# Google Chrome complains about flash when using <embed> with PDF file

Tags: html, pdf, vue.js, embed-tag

I'm building a very simple component in Vue to preview PDF files and images in a modal.

I'm using [Vue Boostrap's modal component](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal/). In the body of the modal I have the following line:

`<embed :src="fileSrc" type="application/pdf" height="100%" width="100%">`

`fileSrc` is a prop that the component receives.

When the modal is launched, the PDF visualizer doesn't show and Google Chrome emits a warning saying:

> Flash is blocked on this page

[image]

I have allowed flash to be displayed on the page but still doesn't work.

If I remove the `type="application/pdf"` attribute and the `fileSrc` is a JPEG file, it shows up just fine.

[image]

I've also tried with the `<object>` tag with no luck.

What should I check? What am I missing?

**Edit: Why is this question not a duplicate?**

Because I wan't to be able to use the `<embed>` tag to support not only PDF but also images for previewing. The examples in [this page](https://pdfobject.com/static/) work without enabling Flash and without warnings, so I should be able to reproduce this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.

The files I was trying to display with the `<embed>` were being uploaded to a bucket in AWS S3. When uploading the files (with a PHP script), the `Content-Type` metadata needed to be set accordingly to the file (i.e. `application/pdf` for PDF files).

The files were being uploaded with a default `Content-Type` value, thus the browser didn't know what to do with it once placed in a `<embed>` tag (the `Content-type` is used to determine which plugin to choose to display).

I found this method to be very easy to implement as a generic file previewer.